# Sort list of iterables by nth element which might not be present in all of them

Tags: python, sorting

Given a list of iterables:

```
li = [(1,2), (3,4,8), (3,4,7), (9,)]
```

I want to sort by the third element if present, otherwise leave the order unchanged. So here the desired output would be:

```
[(1,2), (3,4,7), (3,4,8), (9,)]
```

Using `li.sort(key=lambda x:x[2])` returns an `IndexError`. I tried a custom function:

```
def safefetch(li, idx):
    try:
        return li[idx]
    except IndexError:
        return  # (ie return None)

li.sort(key=lambda x: safefetch(x, 2))
```

But `None` in sorting yields a `TypeError`.

**Broader context**: I first want to sort by the first element, then the second, then the third, etc. until the length of the longest element, ie I want to run several sorts of decreasing privilege (as in SQL's `ORDER BY COL1 , COL2`), while preserving order among those elements that aren't relevant. So: first sort everything by first element; then among the ties on el_1 sort on el_2, etc.. until el_n. My feeling is that calling a sort function on the whole list is probably the wrong approach.

(Note that this was an "XY question": for my actual question, just using `sorted` on tuples is simplest, as Patrick Artner pointed out in the comments. But the question is posed is trickier.)

Comment: Do you want the shorties at the front or at the back?

Comment: IMHO ,the *broader* question should be simpler than the current one: *leave the order unchanged if the element if absent* will probably require to split and join back the list on the items that lack that element.

Comment: @SergeBallesta i think this just means the OP wants a stable sort, because that requirement taken literally is not a deterministic sort. The only order with actual semantic meaning that can be left unchanged is the one between the short ones themselves.

Comment: To be clear: would `[(3,4,7), (3,4,8), (1,2), (9,)]`, or `[(1,2), (9,), (3,4,7), (3,4,8)]` also be an acceptable output? Also, what **problem do you solve** by sorting in this manner? Please try to give us some context.

Comment: Like @SergeBallesta said, I want to leave the order unchanged if the element is absent. I don't mind rolling my own sort function instead of the built-in. So @ Karl Knechtel those would not be acceptable output. Will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Is `numpy` an option here?

Comment: @MustafaAydın very much so!

Comment: If you sort using tuples this IS already the sorted output: `sorted([(3,4,8), (9,), (1,2), (3,4,7) ])` sorted becomes `[(1, 2), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (9,)]` wich is what you want. I do not get it ...

Comment: You changed the text here so the accepted answer becomes irrelevant - the accepted solution does not sort by 1st then 2nd etc elemenbt - it sorts by the 3rd element .. and keeps other locations

Comment: @PatrickArtner you're completely right, this was a classic XY problem ‍♂️ your answer is what I want. Do you think I should rollback the edit so that the accepted answer fits, or just edit to clarify what I asked and what I wanted?

Comment: Rolling back would at least make the answers fit the question again. I think that is better then letting it stay as is where question and answer do not fit at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first get the indices for distinct lengths of elements in the list via a `defaultdict` and then sort each sublist with numpy's fancy indexing:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# {length -> inds} mapping
d = defaultdict(list)

# collect indices per length
for j, tup in enumerate(li):
    d[len(tup)].append(j)

# sort
li = np.array(li, dtype=object)
for inds in d.values():
    li[inds] = sorted(li[inds])

# convert back to list if desired
li = li.tolist()
```

to get `li` at the end as

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (9,)]
```

---

For some other samples:

```
In [134]: the_sorter([(12,), (3,4,8), (3,4,7), (9,)])
Out[134]: [(9,), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (12,)]


In [135]: the_sorter([(12,), (3,4,8,9), (3,4,7), (11, 9), (9, 11), (2, 4, 4, 4)])
Out[135]: [(12,), (2, 4, 4, 4), (3, 4, 7), (9, 11), (11, 9), (3, 4, 8, 9)]
```

where `the_sorter` is above procedure wrapped in a function (name lacks imagination...)

```
def the_sorter(li):
    # {length -> inds} mapping
    d = defaultdict(list)

    # collect indices per length
    for j, tup in enumerate(li):
        d[len(tup)].append(j)

    # sort
    li = np.array(li)
    for inds in d.values():
        li[inds] = sorted(li[inds])
   
    return li.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you return as fallback value must be comparable to the other key values that might be returned. In your example that would require a numerical value.

```
import sys

def safefetch(li, idx):
    try:
        return li[idx]
    except IndexError:
        return sys.maxsize  # largest int possible
```

This would put all the short ones at the back of the sort order, but maintain a stable order among them.

Comment: in the desired output, Short ones stay where they were, though.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Think that through. That would not be deterministic and not solvable at all with Python's standard sorting.

Comment: You can freeze the short ones' positions and sort the suitable ones and put them back. I don't see a strict requirement that one-shot `sort` should do it in the question...But maybe I'm wrong..

Comment: True,then the question is at the very least unclear.

Comment: Upvoted, but I did want to preserve the order so this isn't what i need. Will try edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Mustafa Aydın here is a solution in Pandas. Would prefer one without the memory overhead of a dataframe, but this might be good enough.

```
import pandas as pd

li = [(1,2), (3,4,8), (3,4,7), (9,)]
tmp = pd.DataFrame(li)
[tuple(int(el) for el in t if not pd.isna(el)) for t in tmp.sort_values(by=tmp.columns.tolist()).values]

> [(1, 2), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (9,)]
```